# Best way to fetch value from database to show on React front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to display the value of a collection property stored using mongoose in the client side of my react app when a user clicks a button.

By retrieving the value on click and storing the value using setState.

**My Problem --**
I can't seem to setState and display the new value immediately onClick...
On the next click, the value shown is the value for the previous click.

**my backend node.js code for fetching data from mongodb**

```
app.post('/api/showengagement', async (req, res) => {
const result = await Post.findOne({url: req.body.url}, "likes");
res.send(result);
```

})

**My frontend react.js code for handling onClick and displaying the gotten data**

```
handleLike(url, e){
    if (e.target.innerText.toLowerCase() === "like"){
        axios.post('/api/showengagement', {url: url})
                .then(res => this.setState({
                    likeEngage: res.data.likes
                }));
        e.target.innerText = `This post has ${this.state.likeEngage} like(s)`
        axios.post('/api/incrementlikes', {url: url});
    }
    else{
        e.target.innerText = "Like";
        axios.post('/api/decrementlikes', {url: url});
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the wrong value because you are setting the `e.target.innerText` before the `axios.post` is done. You can move that code into the callback to get the desired order of operations like this:

```
handleLike = (url, e) => {
    if (e.target.innerText.toLowerCase() === "like"){
        axios.post('/api/showengagement', {url: url})
        .then(res => {          
          e.target.innerText = `This post has ${res.data.likes} like(s)`
         });
        axios.post('/api/incrementlikes', {url: url});
    }
    else{
        e.target.innerText = "Like";
        axios.post('/api/decrementlikes', {url: url});
    }
}
```

By doing it this way you don't even need to store the value in `state`. You can still do that if it's needed elsewhere in the code though.

The reason your setting of `innerText` happened before the value came back is that the `axios.post` is asynchronous, and returns before the operation is done and your function continues to the next line (setting the text to the old value). The new value comes in later when the `post` completes and your callback function is called.

#### Even Better: Avoid Using innerText - Use render()

Another way to do this is to have your `render()` function be responsible for writing the value in the appropriate place using the `state` variable. When you call `this.setState()` it causes the component to render again and you would see the value appear. Here is a working React class that shows it:

```
import React from "react";

let likes = [];
let urls = ["url1", "url2"];

class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { likeEngages: [] };  // initialize the array of likeEngages
  }
  // fake implementation of 'post' instead of axios.post 
  post = (url, body) => {
    if (!likes[body.id]) likes[body.id] = 1;
    if (url === "/api/showengagement") {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: { likes: likes[body.id] } });
    } else {
      likes[body.id]++; // increment Likes for given id
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
  };

  handleLike = (url, e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    this.post("/api/showengagement", { url, id }).then(res => {
      const engages = this.state.likeEngages;
      engages[id] = res.data.likes;  // set the likes count in the state
      this.setState({ likeEngages: engages });
    });
    this.post("/api/incrementlikes", { url, id });
  };

  showLikes = id => {
    if (this.state.likeEngages[id])
      return (
        <span>
          {" This post has " + this.state.likeEngages[id] + " like(s)"}
        </span>
      );
    return " No likes yet";
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button id="id1" onClick={e => this.handleLike(urls[0], e)}>
              Like1
            </button>
            {this.showLikes("id1")}
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="id2" onClick={e => this.handleLike(urls[1], e)}>
              Like2
            </button>
            {this.showLikes("id2")}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: It threw an error `Cannot set property 'innerText' of null` . I'm guessing this is because the `axios.post` function cannot access the `e` parameter in handleLike()

Comment: I changed `handleList` to be defined with => syntax. try that - it may help

Comment: if not, then go back to using state, but when using state you might as well keep the logic of displaying the value within your `render` as shown in the 2nd part

Comment: did you try moving the display of the value into your `render` function? The flow is that you set state in your `post` callback, and use it in your `render`

Comment: yes i did... but the problem there is, i'm using a _list component_, meaning that each list item which is gotten from a state array, has a different _value for likes_.. and I can't use another array to save the likes for each list item because i don't know how to link a _like value_ to the correct list item....

Comment: I edited my answer at the bottom to show how you can keep an array of `likeEngage` values rather than just one and show them per list item. You just need some id to identify each.

Comment: I've been trying to get my head around this... because i got a syntax error around `this.state.likeEngages` and the terminator used at the end of the statement

Comment: I had an error in the `.then` statement. Try again - it needs to initialize the `likeEngages` to an empty array if it hasn't been set yet.

Comment: @David, I updated the answer to include a working example (I tried it on `codesandbox.io`). It shows 2 buttons and keeps a running count of likes for each button separately. I hope it gives you the idea of how to do similar in your program.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as correct if you’re happy with it

Answer (score 0):

Update your setState to the following;

```
this.setState({...this.state, likeEngage: res.data.likes})
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, you will need to call the incrementLikes after setState like below

```
this.setState({...this.state, likeEngage: res.data.likes}, () => incrementlikes(url))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. I also don't have an `incrementLikes(url)` function. Only as a post request endpoint

Comment: The code won't work straight away like that, you will need to destructure it so that `incrementlikes()` will be a function.
Also, the best way to go about this is to use state in your render as @always-learning suggested.

Comment: yes i used state in my render... but the problem there is, i'm using a _list component_, meaning that each list item which is gotten from a state array, has a different _value for likes_.. and I can't use another array to save the likes for each list item because i don't know how to link a _like value_ to the correct list item....